# Dynamic scrollable Table with fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I know there are a lot of solutions for a fixed header and I tried almost all of the examples but none of them worked out exactly how I wanted it to be.
I am trying for four days now to create a table with followed specs:

- The table should have a fixed header
- The table should have the class "table table bordered" from bootstrap
- The table is not of top of the web page there are some other elements above it
- The width sould be 100%
- The table should have 10 colums
- The columns should not be all the same distribution should be like this:
  10%|9%|8%|11%|8%|9%|8%|12%|20%|5% if something in this column is longer than this it should make a line break
- The table should have an height about "55vh"
- If the table is longer than the height it should be scrollable
- If the browser window gets smaller the website replaces the elements because I use the grid system but the table should stay with the size it had before and a scollbar for the x-axsis should appear
- The columns from the table body  should always be the same size like the columns from the table head

I also tried different solutions with Jquery but none of them worked like I wanted to. Would be great if you could help me with my problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Would be good to se what you have tried in this past four days to take it as a starting point.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u39fn1jc/3/

Comment: Even if I have overflow hidden I am able to scroll in the chrome or IE browser

Comment: I can't scroll via Chrome on mac.

Comment: the class "table responsive" affected this with bootstrapper so this problem solved